# Read from array and calculate average

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write code that reads a row of characters from an array, assign the characters to an integer and then average all the integers of the row, it does this for every row in the array. Here is what I have so far :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));

while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    int gp = 0;
    double gpa = 0;
    String line = in.nextLine();

    if(line.length() == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    line = line.substring(line.length()-15, line.length());

    String[] letters = line.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

    if (letters[i].equals("H")) {
        gp += 7;
    }
    else if (letters[i].equals("D")) {
        gp += 6;
    }
    else if (letters[i].equals("C")) {
        gp += 5;
    }
    else if (letters[i].equals("P")) {
        gp += 4;
    }
    else if (letters[i].equals("F")) {
        gp += 0;
    }
    }

    gpa = gp / letters.length;

    System.out.println(gpa);
}
```

Here is the array that i am working with :

```
[, D, D, C, P, H, H, C]
[, H, H, H, D, D, H, H]
[, C, F, C, D, C, C, C]
[, F, F, F, P, C, C, C]
[, F, C, F, C, D, P, D]
[, D, D, F, D, D, F, D]
[, P, F, P, F, P, F, P]
```

Here is the current output of the code :

```
5.0
6.0
3.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
2.0
```

Contents of the text file :

```
45721 Chris Jones D D C P H H C D
87946 Jack Aaron H H H D D H H H
43285 Ben Adams C F C D C C C P
24679 Chuck Doherty F F F P C C C F
57652 Dean Betts F C F C D P D H
67842 Britney Dowling D D F D D F D D
22548 Kennedy Blake P F P F P F P P
```

Am I on the right path? would there be an easier method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best way to tell if you're doing it right is also the simplest: run your code and check the answer!

Comment: @musical_coder my mistake, i have run the code and just printed the output but it only displays the value of the the first letter of each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick note to save you some grief later

Shouldn't

```
line = line.substring(line.length()-16, line.length()-1);
```

be instead

```
line = line.substring(line.length()-15, line.length());
```

to get all the grades?

And then you'll need to put your if statements into a for loop, that loops over each value of the array (replace the `letters[1]` with `letters[i]`)

Comment: I have updated my code with the line.length change and the for loop suggested, i have also added the output which still seems to be incorrect as the actual sum of the first row should be 46. Am i missing something?

Comment: The other lines outputs seem to be getting the right values... Is there a mistaken character in the first line (a tab instead of a space)? edit: actually the second line is also wrong, maybe check those first two lines for any issues, even the line break?

Comment: Both the array and the text file that i am reading from seem to be consistent for all rows, i will post the contents of the text file

Comment: Woop, you're cutting off the last grade for starters, need to drop the -1 I think, and you were probably better with -15 instead of 16 or 20.

Comment: ah yes thank you that solved it, the sums are all correct. I have now updated my code to try and produce the average for each row except the output is once again incorrect, the first row should read 5.75. Are you able to see any noticeable mistake?

Comment: Try casting the bottom value as a double by using (double)letters.length, it could be an issue with that, often a trap

Comment: i have already initialized the variable gpa as a double above

Comment: Yes, but you're dividing an int by an int, so it outputs an int. It's a language quirk, and like I said, an easy trap.

Comment: ah yes my mistake! i changed the variable gp to double as well and it is now printing the correct values, thank you for you help.